# What makes an uniform buffer object active?

Tags: opengl, uniform

OpenGL function `glGetActiveUniformBlockName()` is documented [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetActiveUniformBlockName.xml). The short description reads:

> [it] retrieves the name of the active uniform block at uniformBlockIndex within program.`

How can I make an uniform block *active*?

Answer (score 2):

A uniform block is active in the same way that a uniform is active: you use it in some series of expressions that yields an output. If you want a uniform block to be active, you need to actually do something with one of its members that materially affects the outputs of a shader.

Comment: compiler usually tries to optimize the code and for instance removes the unused variables - uniforms for this purpose. You can use "#pragma optimize(off)" to test the shader...

Comment: Can you fen?  Is that driver specific?  I been looking for details of some way of using a pre-processor type directives with shaders but haven't found much info.  Actually started writing my own parser to allow me to do conditional compilation and things like that!

Comment: @Robinson: How much the driver listens to that #pragma is driver-specific, but the existence of it is mandatory. And GLSL has a full pre-processor, just like C (more or less).

Answer (score 1):

According to the OpenGL documentation, the definition of an "active" uniform block is implementation-dependent, so it's up to the driver. But if you only need to make a block "active", then just use it in your GLSL code. As long as you've used a uniform in the block, the block is guaranteed to be active.

However, if you don't use it, the block may be either active or inactive, depending on your hardware. Even if you marked the block to use the `std140` layout, the compiler can still optimize it away. The tricky part is that, your driver may even treat uniform blocks and uniform block arrays differently. Here's an example:

```c
#version 460

layout(std140, binding = 0) uniform Camera {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 direction;
} camera;

layout(std140, binding = 1) uniform Foo {
    float foo;
    vec3 vec_foo;
} myFoo[2];

layout(std140, binding = 3) uniform Bar {
    float bar;
    vec3 vec_bar;
} myBar[4];

layout(std140, binding = 7) uniform Baz {
    float baz1;
    float baz2;
};

void main() {
    vec3 use_camera = camera.position;  // use the Camera block
    vec3 use_foo = myFoo[0].vec_foo;    // use the Foo block
    color = vec4(1.0);
}
```

In this fragment shader, we have 8 `std140` uniform blocks, the `Camera` and `Foo` block are being used, so they must be active. On the other hand, `Bar` and `Baz` are not being used, so you may think they are inactive, but on my machine, while `Bar` is inactive, `Baz` is still considered active. I'm not sure if I can replicate the result on other machines, but you can test it out by using the [example code](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Program_Introspection#Examples) from OpenGL documentation.

Since it's implementation-dependent, the safest way of using uniform blocks is to always experiment on your hardware. If you want stable results on all machines, the only way is to use them all, otherwise it can be hard. As others have suggested, you can try to turn off the compiler optimization as below, but unfortunately, this still won't stop an unused block from being optimized out, because removing inactive uniforms is not an optimization, it's just how the compiler works.

```c
#pragma optimize(off)
...
```